# Keras: Modify/Rearrange elements of Input Layer to create a new Input Layer and feed the new input Layer to create a new Output

Tags: python, tensorflow, recursion, keras, neural-network

Suppose that I have a Keras Input Layer "input_layer_A" (in Python)

```
input_layer_A = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(10, ), name="input_A") # shape = (None, 10)
```

I also have a dense layer

```
dense_layer_1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, activation='tanh', name="dense_layer_1")
```

Then I create an output as:

```
out1 = dense_layer_1(input_layer_A)
```

I want to modify/edit a copy of "input_layer_A" (as an example) as follows: (syntax on how to edit the Input Layer properly is a part of the question)

```
input_layer_B = input_layer_A  #Copy the input_layer_A to create new input_layer_B

input_layer_B[0][5] = input_layer_B[0][4]  #Replace 5th element with its 4th element

input_layer_B[0][4] = out1  #Replace the 4th element with previous output out1
```

Is it the correct way to edit/modify the input Layer? If not what is the proper way?

Then I feed “input_layer_B” to “dense_layer_1” to create a new output “out2” (kind of a recursion and it can be applied in a for loop as well)

```
out2 = dense_layer_1(input_layer_B)
```

Finally create the model

```
model = Model(inputs=[input_layer_A], outputs = [out1, out2])
```

When I run the model I get an error in the form of (related with out2: this is where the graph becomes disconnected, no problem for out1, which means there is something wrong about how I modify the "input_layer_B")

**ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor**

What is the correct way to modify/edit an Input Layer so that I can still use it to feed successfully to "dense_layer_1" to end up with a connected and proper graph?

Any help, suggestion or an alternative method to accomplish what I want is appreciated.

Thank you

*PS: My motivation for building such a recursive network is to model a NARX Neural Network with feedback to estimate multi-step ahead output of a dynamical system. So there can be n-many outputs in theory*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
input_layer_A = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(10, ), name="input_A") # shape = (None, 10)
dense_layer_1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, activation='tanh', name="dense_layer_1")
out1 = dense_layer_1(input_layer_A)
out2 = tf.concat([input_layer_A[:, :4], out1, input_layer_A[:, 4][..., tf.newaxis], input_layer_A[:, 6:]], -1)
out2 = dense_layer_1(out2)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[input_layer_A], outputs = [out1, out2])

inp = tf.random.uniform((1, 10))
pred = model(inp)
```

Note, that I've changed dimension of Dense layer (it should be 1 to get the following op possible):

```
input_layer_B[0][4] = out1
```

Comment: Hi Andrey, your suggestion looks promising. I will try it ASAP. You were absolutely right in changing the dimension of Dense Layer to 1. I had just set it to be 12 to provide an example and forgot that it would not lead to a scalar value in out1. I will provide feedback on what I get as soon as I try your suggestion!

Comment: I am modifying the dimension of the Dense Layer to 1 in the question so as not to let people think that it was the culprit

Comment: In your line “out2 = tf.concat([input_layer_A[:, :4], out1, input_layer_A[:, 4][..., tf.newaxis], input_layer_A[:, 6:]], -1)”, what is the function of “[..., tf.newaxis]” ? Thanks

Comment: Tried it. Solves the problem!